# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Apple iPad 3 (iOS 7 non-jailbroken) USB connection problem

Tags: usb, connection, ipad, ios

I've bought an Apple iPad 3 (iOS 7 non-jailbroken), and I'm trying to connect it to my PC running Ubuntu 12.04 through the original USB cable.

After I plugged in the cable, I got this message on the PC:

```
The device 'iPad' is locked. Enter the passcode on the device and click 'Try again'.
```

Slide to unlock on iPad, it's OK, I got this message on the PC again:

```
The device 'iPad' is locked. Enter the passcode on the device and click 'Try again'.
```

iPad: `Trust this computer? TRUST/DON'T TRUST` I've selected TRUST.

PC:

```
 Unable to mount - DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

OK, I've read some forums, everywhere there was this solution: `"Install: ifuse, libimobiledevice-utils, Rhythmbox`

OK, I've installed them through terminal, and used the `idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair` command also in the terminal. Then I got this message:

```
Device is not paired with this host.
```

I don't know what to do. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug for IOS.7.0.2:
You can see:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1215098